# Javascript filter between two string dates in Vue component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm working with Vue in a Laravel app. Everything below works except the last one. I can't seem to find the right search terms to fit this situation. Sorry if it's a duplicate.

Here is my current code:

```
return [...this.tableData].filter((salesorders) => {
     if (this.selectOption == '6') {
         return salesorders.order_status.match(this.status);
    }

                if (this.selectOption == '1') {
                    return salesorders.number.includes(this.searchInput);
                }

                if (this.selectOption == '2' && this.choice == 'is') {
                    var ship_date = moment(String(this.first_date)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    return salesorders.requested_ship_date.match(ship_date);
                }

                if (this.selectOption == '2' && this.choice == 'is not') {
                    var ship_date = moment(String(this.first_date)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    return !salesorders.requested_ship_date.match(ship_date);
                }

                if (this.selectOption == '2' && this.choice == 'is between') {
                    var ship_date1 = moment(String(this.first_date)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
                    var ship_date2 = moment(String(this.end_date)).format('MM-DD-YYYY');

                    return salesorders.requested_ship_date >= ship_date1 && salesorders.requested_ship_date >= ship_date2;
                }

            });
```

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/

Comment: `salesorders.requested_ship_date` is just a string, whereas ship_date1 and ship_date2 are moment objects, you need to convert the `salesorders.requested_ship_date` to a moment object and use date comparator functions such as `.isAfter` or `.diff`

Comment: I forgot to mention that salesorders.requested_ship_date is an array. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

```
    return salesorders.requested_ship_date >= ship_date1 && salesorders.requested_ship_date <= ship_date2;
```